# How to determine if type member is an enum?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums

I figured out that I can use `GetMembers()` to return the members of the class, but I would like to return only the enum members. While debugging I can hover over `member` and see an `IsEnum` property that is `true`, but I can't seem to get to it in code.

I would like for only `IAmAnEnum` to be printed in the following code. Currently the code will print both `IAmAnEnum` as well as `IAmAClass`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var member in typeof(Test).GetMembers())
    {
        //if (member.IsEnum) // <-- Compile error
        //{
        Console.WriteLine(member.Name);
        //}
    }

    Console.Read();
}

public class Test
{
    public enum IAmAnEnum
    {

    }

    public class IAmAClass
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsEnum` is a property of `Type`.

If the member is in fact a type, you can cast it to `Type` and get the property there.

Comment: Thanks! I have to wait 11 minutes to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

The GetMembers method on the Type, returns an array of MemberInfo objects.
On each of them, you have a *MemberType* property.
Use this, to get the type of the member.
On the type of the member, you can freely use the IsEnum check.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: OK I see what you are saying now. In this case both the class and the enum have a `MemberType` of `MemberTypes.NestedType`, which tells me it's a `Type`, so I can *safely* cast it to `Type` with that information. The solution I'm using now uses `if (member is Type) { ((Type)member).IsEnum ... }`, but now I see I could use `if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.NestedType) {((Type)member).IsEnum ... }`. In the end though I was just missing the fact that I needed to cast it to `Type` in the first place.